# "Read message" report in e-mail in android

Tags: android, email, client

I am creating an e-mail client in android. I want to receive the report when my e-mail is been opened at the receivers end. Eg. In outlook we have a read message request, if we use this option the sender will be notified about the message being opened at the receivers end. I used the eclient app from github to start with. I want to be strong on reporting side. any help would be appreciated..

Comment: what u have tried so far? post some code

Comment: Hi Sankar, I am a beginner and I was just browsing the net and I could not find any solution. As I said I have tried eclient app that is in github which does not have read message report functionality. My research is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need the app to be installed on both ends.  There's no way to know otherwise-  you need to be able to run a program on the recipient's computer.  Which is why everyone I know has stopped even trying read receipts in Outlook-  if the recipient uses any other mail reader it won't send anything.  Given the extreme unlikeliness of that happening for all possible recipients of email, this only makes even remote sense if you're in a locked down corporate environment where only your app is allowed to access email on any device.

Comment: Thanks Gabe.. I felt the same. But I was just looking for a work around. If any one has any solutions or work around plz do let me know. As this is part of my client requirement either I have to say I cant provide this functionality or provide the client with the same... Thanks!!

Comment: There are some old and unethical tricks you can do with embedding html objects in the email.  But they're still unreliable-  it proves only that something downloaded the embedded image, which could also be a virus scanner, proxy, or an email client trying to cache data for someone to read later.